# Slow SQL Server query using a DB2 linked server in virtual environment

Tags: sql-server, performance, db2, linked-server, virtualisation, query-performance

I have a problem with a slow query which uses a linked server. Let me list out my environment first and I'll get to the issue:

- Virtual Windows 2003 R2 server (fresh deployments on XenServer 6.1 & ESXi 5)
- SQL Server 2005 SP3
- Linked Server created using IBM DB2 for iBMASQL OLE DB Provider
  [image]
- The query itself is a select statement with a where clause which selects transactions this month.
  [image]

Alright, so the issue itself:

- Virtual machine is set to 4 vCores, it takes roughly 35 seconds to complete
- Virtual machine is set to 2 vCores, it takes roughly 20 seconds to complete
- Virtual machine is set to 1 vCores, it takes roughly 5 seconds to complete

I've tried tinkering with:

- Network card settings
- MAXDOP 1 OPTION
- Looking at the execution plan

I'm at a loss as to what to do from here on. We want to use 4 vCores as the server will be heavily used. However, the queries take a lot longer when compared to using only 1 vCore.

Is there any possible way to limit the amount of vCores the linked server uses?

Is there anything else that I should take a look at?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using four-part notation or OPENQUERY()? With OPENQUERY, SQL Server does less work locally and pushes more of the effort to the remote server. Are you getting a parallel plan when there are more than 1 vCores available and the query allows it (ie, not using MAXDOP)?

Comment: I've a screenshot of the query and the execution plan without using MAXDOP. Parallelism isn't used in the plan and as I expected, MAXDOP doesn't help. I haven't tried using OPENQUERY as I am not aware of this, but I will look into it now.

Comment: Using OPENQUERY didn't make any difference unfortunately.

Comment: If you affinitize SQL Server to only use 1 processor out of the 2 or 4 available, does that also fix the problem?

Comment: Since the plan is not parallel and SQLS will only run it on one core, I'm thinking that the problem is more likely on the virtualisation side than the SQL side. I don't know much at all about Xen, but my normal virtualisation troubleshooting questions are: Is your VM host busy? Is there memory or cpu pressure on the host that the VM doesn't see? Is your SQL VM moving between processors or between hosts? Is there a problem with NUMA?

Comment: I should have been a bit more clear, but these VMs are on a new host and the VMs are newly deployed for this purpose. No other content / VM / data / traffic is on these boxes. The VM host is enterprise grade equipment with plenty of processing power and memory available.

I do agree that this may be a virtual environment issue with no particular fix available. We may end up having to go back to a physical solution.

I will try to affinitize the SQL Server and see if we still see the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure the query is optimized first.  Run it directly on the linked server (i.e. run it locally on the DB2 machine) and make sure the indexes support your query.  I also noticed you are not wrapping your dates in quotes.  This may end up in a non SARGable query, causing a table scan on the target.  Do you need every single column returned?  If not, name the columns specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Jon Seigel, it seems like the issue in part due to the CPU affinity setting in SQL.

We deployed this VM with SQL from an image which causes a known issue as listed here (scenario #3):

- [IBM - Slow performance in Controller due to inability to use available CPU cores in SQL server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21615289)

Removing the automatic affinity option and setting the affinity mask option to use all the CPUs available resolved the issue.

- [Affinity Mask Option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187104(v=sql.90).aspx)

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'affinity mask', 15;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

[image: sql server affinity GUI]

We have updated our image to include this option. Thanks everyone for the help in this issue.

---

Please note, this option is deprecated in SQL Server 2012 and is not recommended for use. Additionally, it is related to processor thread handling in Windows 2000 and Windows 2003 operating systems.

- [Affinity Mask Option - SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187104(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad it was an easy fix!

Comment: You should mark this the answer.

Comment: I need to wait 24 hours before I can mark my own answer. Will do so later today. :)